# What is a dynamical description of phase transition?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition

In standard textbooks, it seems only giving a phenomenological description (like Landau paradigm, etc.). Is there a dynamical description？

Comment: under the heading "The Stefan Problem" you can find references to the problem of the growth and propagation of the interface between two phases, or start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of classical phase transitions, two relevant keywords are dynamical critical phenomena and time-dependent Ginzburg-Landau theory. It's a rich field, covered in more specialized textbooks like Nigel Goldenfeld's *Lectures on Phase Transitions and the Renormalization Group*. Quantum systems also allow for more exotic, inherently [dynamical phase transitions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245253/49107).